# .htaccess avoid accessing files with .php after rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I applied a rewrite rule to show my php files without the .php at the end of the file. This is what I have:

```
##Quitar extensión .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But the problem I have is that I can access that file with two ways. With or without the .php. For example: `mywebsite.com/file.php` and  `mywebsite.com/file` both work but I just want the second one to work so I  need to add something to my `.htaccess` file to redirect `mywebsite.com/file.php` to  `mywebsite.com/file` or show a 404 error. But I think the first option is better.

Is it possible to combine my .htaccess code with what I want? And if so, what is needed to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to remove .php extension

```
RewriteEngine on
#1)externally redirect from "/file.php" to "/file"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
#2)internally map "/file" to "/file.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: I found a problem by doing this. Every ajax call I had is not workign now as I accessed them as `'ajaxexample.php'`. Does it have any solution?